# EDIT : JAVA(Swing) :Is there any features in java(Swing) to hold Html page like webview in javafx

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

how I can achieve to link my Html page as it is inside my Swing application like web view in javafx using JEditor it Works but not support css Style and other Javascript code ....

Comment: While Swing's HTML rendering engine only supports HTML 3.2, and not even all of that, I'm *pretty sure* it supports `colspan` of a `table` column correctly.  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: @AndrewThompson is correct; see `help.html` in this [example](http://robotchase.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Swing's HTML rendering engine only supports HTML 3.2, and not even all of that, it supports `colspan` (and `rowspan`) of a `table` cell correctly.

Here is an example (in the form of an MCVE):

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class HTMLTableColSpan {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    int left = 706;
    int right = 707;
    int up = 708;
    int down = 709;
    int infinity = 8734;

    HTMLTableColSpan() {
        initUI();
    }

    public void initUI() {
        if (ui != null) {
            return;
        }

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4, 4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4, 4, 4, 4));

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(
                "<html><body style='font-family: san-serif'>");

        sb.append("<table border=1>");

        sb.append("<tr>");
        sb.append(getTableCell("&#" + right + ";", 2, 1));
        sb.append(getTableCell("&#" + down + ";", 1, 2));
        sb.append("</tr>");

        sb.append("<tr>");
        sb.append(getTableCell("&#" + up + ";", 1, 2));
        sb.append(getTableCell("&#" + infinity + ";", 1, 1));
        sb.append("</tr>");

        sb.append("<tr>");
        sb.append(getTableCell("&#" + left + ";", 2, 1));
        sb.append("</tr>");

        sb.append("</table></body></html>");

        ui.add(new JLabel(sb.toString()));
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    private static String getTableCell(String data, int colspan, int rowspan) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("<td colspan=");
        sb.append(colspan);
        sb.append(" rowspan=");
        sb.append(rowspan);
        sb.append(" style='font-size: 50px;'>");

        sb.append(data);

        sb.append("</td>");

        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                HTMLTableColSpan o = new HTMLTableColSpan();

                JFrame f = new JFrame("HTML Table colspan");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi...Andrew Thank you For reply...but i have different Scenario Actually My HTML Page is auto Generated while processing and i Want to Display it inside JtabbedPane  Using JEditor It Show But In different form

Comment: *"Hi...Andrew Thank you For reply...but i have.."*  ..but you sill have **not** posted an MCVE as I advised before I even posted this answer.